# How to convert gml:pos to latitude and longitude?

Tags: wms, latitude-longitude, gml, epsg

I'm trying to figure out the latitude and longitude of rail stations that are contained in [this WMS feature list](http://inspire.misoportal.com/geoserver/transport_direct_railnetwork/wfs?service=wfs&version=2.0.0&request=GetFeature&typeName=transport_direct_railnetwork:stations). I'm completely new to the GIS field, so please forgive me if I use the wrong terms below. I've done quite a bit of reverse engineering and fiddling to get this far.

The first station has the following location:

```xml
<gml:Point srsName="urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::27700" srsDimension="2">
  <gml:pos>450077 356089</gml:pos> 
</gml:Point>
```

After some research, I've concluded this position is relative to offsets and I've used the [EPSG](http://www.epsg-registry.org) site to look up code `27700`. This shows me:

> Latitude of natural origin: 49° N
>   Longitude of natural origin: 2° W
>   Scale factor at natural origin: 0.9996012717
>   False easting: 400,000 (metre)
>   False northing: 100,000 (metre)

I'm guessing the values in my station location have had 400,000 and 100,000 respectively added to them. So if I subtract those values I would get:

```
50077, 256089
```

But I'm not sure what these values represent. They are minuscule, so they can't be metres from the latitude/logitude point (0,0).

Can anyone point out where I've gone wrong? My goal is to eventually convert this `gml:pos` value into latitude and longitude.

Comment: depending on the language you are using some version of proj4 will do all the calculations for you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are almost right:

The false Northing is -100000, so the "real" Y coordinate is 456089 meters.

The point is 50 km East and 456 km North of the natural origin, that is 2° West and 49° North.

Here you see a grid of EPSG:27700 together with the origin and your railway station:

[image]

Comment: Ahah! It seems so obvious when you point it out :-) Thanks for unblocking my investigations...