# Convert from EPSG:27700 to latitude and longitude

Tags: java, latitude-longitude, wgs84, proj

I'm trying to transform [EPSG:27700](http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/27700/html/) coordinates to latitude and longitude. From my research I understand that WGS 84 (EPSG:4326) is the SRS that resembles latitude and longitude.

I'm using [Proj4j](https://trac.osgeo.org/proj4j/) to try and convert a test coordinate (those familiar with [my previous question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/205838/how-to-convert-gmlpos-to-latitude-and-longitude/205839#205839) will recognise Kirkby In Ashfield station).

My Java code snippet:

```
String projection27700 = "+proj=tmerc +lat_0=49 +lon_0=-2 +k=0.9996012717 "
    + "+x_0=400000 +y_0=-100000 +ellps=airy +datum=OSGB36 +units=m +no_defs";
CRSFactory crsFactory = new CRSFactory();
CoordinateReferenceSystem sourceSRS = crsFactory.createFromParameters(null,
    projection27700);

String projection4326 = "+proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +no_defs";
CoordinateReferenceSystem targetSRS = crsFactory.createFromParameters(null,
    projection4326);

CoordinateTransform transformation = new BasicCoordinateTransform(sourceSRS,
    targetSRS);

ProjCoordinate result = new ProjCoordinate();
ProjCoordinate input = new ProjCoordinate(450077, 356089);
transformation.transform(input, result);

System.out.println(result.x + ", " + result.y);
```

The result printed is:

```
-155.20355661333892, -35.91545136124713
```

This doesn't seem right - it neither makes sense as degrees or metres (to me at least). Have I missed out a conversion somewhere, either on my input data or in this output data I've produced?

I'm fairly happy my input data is right, based on [this documentation](https://github.com/OSGeo/proj.4/wiki/GenParms#units), which confirms that `+units=m` will allow my input data to be in metres. It also suggests the output data should be in degrees, which is what I want.

Comment: Try adding `+towgs84=446.448,-125.157,542.06,0.15,0.247,0.842,-20.489` to the `projection27700` string.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't solved the original problem, but I've worked around it by using [CTS](https://github.com/orbisgis/cts) instead.

```
CRSFactory crsFactory = new CRSFactory();

// Download the data files from Github and place on the class path
RegistryManager registryManager = crsFactory.getRegistryManager();
registryManager.addRegistry(new EPSGRegistry());
CoordinateReferenceSystem crs4326 = crsFactory.getCRS("EPSG:4326");
CoordinateReferenceSystem crs27700 = crsFactory.getCRS("EPSG:27700");

// These ugly casts seem unavoidable
List<CoordinateOperation> operations = CoordinateOperationFactory
    .createCoordinateOperations((GeodeticCRS) crs27700, (GeodeticCRS) crs4326);

double[] result = operations.get(0).transform(new double[] {450077, 356089});
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(result));
```

This produces:

`[-1.2535570562769147, 53.09965984661543]`

which is the [correct answer](https://goo.gl/maps/QA2VrUdCzFK2).

Answer (score 1):

The proj4 string that GDAL version 2.3-dev is using is as follows:

```
gdalsrsinfo epsg:27700

PROJ.4 : '+proj=tmerc +lat_0=49 +lon_0=-2 +k=0.9996012717 +x_0=400000 +y_0=-100
00 +ellps=airy +towgs84=446.448,-125.157,542.06,0.15,0.247,0.842,-20.489 +units
m +no_defs'
```

Transformation with gdaltransform utility gives correct answer:

```
gdaltransform -s_srs epsg:27700 -t_srs epsg:4326
450077, 356089
-1.25355705622145 53.0996598531095 49.0407739514485
```

Adding the datum as used in your proj4 string has only very small effect:

```
gdaltransform -s_srs "+proj=tmerc +lat_0=49 +lon_0=-2 +k=0.
9996012717 + +x_0=400000 +y_0=-100000 +ellps=airy +datum=OSGB36 +units=m +no_def
s" -t_srs epsg:4326
450077, 356089
-1.2535571019191 53.0996598519711 49.0382279874757
```

I am not sure what goes wrong but it seems that the error is in your code and not in proj4.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is Apache SIS - http://sis.apache.org. I found it cleaner and faster than most solutions:

```
val sourceCRS = CRS.forCode("EPSG:27700")
val targetCRS = CRS.forCode("EPSG:4326")

val operation = CRS.findOperation(sourceCRS, targetCRS, null)

// Threadsafe: https://sis.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/sis/referencing/operation/transform/AbstractMathTransform.html
val transform = operation.getMathTransform

val ptSrc = new DirectPosition2D(450077, 356089)
val ptDst = transform.transform(ptSrc, null)

println("Source: " + ptSrc)
println("Target: " + ptDst)
```

This produces:

```
Source: POINT(450077 356089)
Target: POINT(53.09965984661642 -1.2535570562768357)
```

For dependencies you'd need:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.sis.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>sis-referencing</artifactId>
        <version>0.8</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.sis.non-free</groupId>
        <artifactId>sis-embedded-data</artifactId>
        <version>0.8</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
```